# No response from server after a esp8266 POST request

Tags: arduino, at-command, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I'm pretty new with esp8266 and i have a problem. It would be nice if someone could help me :)

My problem is; when i send a post request to a website from my esp-01 and i could not receive any response header.
I know that the website is fine, because it works when sending a post request with http://requestmaker.com (and i receive the header and data too)

So, why I'm not receiving any responses via the esp8266, while I'm using the same post request??

**So, this are my commands in the serial monitor:**

```
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","franz95.000webhostapp.com",80

CONNECT
OK
AT+CIPSEND=162

OK
> POST /esp8266_receiver.php HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: franz95.000webhostapp.com\r\nAccept: */*\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length: 9\r\n\r\ndata=1234

busy s...

SEND OK
CLOSED
```

**This is my header:**

```
POST /esp8266_receiver.php HTTP/1.1
Host: franz95.000webhostapp.com
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 9

data=1234
```

**This is the header response with requestmaker.com:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 21 Mar 2017 23:23:50 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Server: awex
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Request-ID: 2c8d35a7a44ec64045f1059343a72b44

<p>EXITO : Se ha logrado escribir en el documento, data =1234</p>
```

Comment: Typing `\n` into the serial monitor sends both a `/` and `n` characters not a single new-line character.

Comment: How i should send CR and NL throw the serial monitor?

Comment: Could you please paste the command you used in the end? I'm not sure what you mean by "the ascii characters of CR and LF" and I'm facing the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use transparent transmission mode by switching

```
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","franz95.000webhostapp.com",80
CONNECT
OK    
AT+CIPMODE=1
OK
AT+CIPSEND
>
```

And copy paste your header to the console to pass the data.

Comment: It doesn't work, it should work as I typed in serial monitor..any other idea?

Comment: No, \n is just a one byte as NL. But you send \ + n, 2 bytes. Open up a Notepad++ and be sure your CR + NL included to the header.

Comment: A doc related with Notepad++ : https://superuser.com/questions/545461/replace-carriage-return-and-line-feed-in-notepad

Comment: @Franz95 given a try ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you have right! it seems i was sending \ + n, (two bytes). I proved sending the ascii characters of CR and LF and it works!!

Comment: Good to know that @Franz95 :)